# HTTP Request working in cURL but not in urllib2.request?

Tags: python, curl

I have this cURL command which runs as expected:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Api-Key:75b5cc58a5cdc0a583f91301cefedf0c" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "http://localhost:8080/app?client_id=ef5f7a03-58e8-48d7-a38a-abbd2696bdb6&grant_type=refresh_token&username=user1&password=password&refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
```

This command return a JSON.

I tried to emulate this call using `urllib2`.

```
request_url = "http://localhost:8080/app"
values = {
        "client_id": "ef5f7a03-58e8-48d7-a38a-abbd2696bdb6",
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
        "username": "user1",
        "password": "password"
        "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
    }

data = urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(request_url, data)
req.add_header("Api-Key", "75b5cc58a5cdc0a583f91301cefedf0c")
req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

print request_url
print req.get_data()
print req.get_method()
print req.get_full_url()
```

This is the output that I get:

```
http://localhost:8080/app
username=user1&password=password&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9&client_id=ef5f7a03-58e8-48d7-a38a-abbd2696bdb6
POST
http://localhost:8080/app
```

The above `urllib2.request` returns me error code 401 which means that the refresh_token that I send is incorrect.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cURL command passes the values as query parameters as part of the URL. The urllib2 command passes the values as POST data. You should probably use:

```
request_url = "http://localhost:8080/app"
values = {
        "client_id": "ef5f7a03-58e8-48d7-a38a-abbd2696bdb6",
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
        "username": "user1",
        "password": "password"
        "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
    }
request_url = request_url + "?" + urlencode(values)
data = ""
req = urllib2.Request(request_url, data)
req.add_header("Api-Key", "75b5cc58a5cdc0a583f91301cefedf0c")
req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Two remarks:

1. this uses a POST method with empty data to mimic the cURL command
   that does the same.
2. standard OAuth 2.0 uses POST for requests to
   the token endpoint (which seems what this request is about), so your
   Python code would be correct

Answer (score 0):

May be the server doesn't  not allow the cross serve call.You should allow the cross serve call on your api server.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Cors/

Answer (score 0):

In your curl request the data is passing to the server as a query parameters. So, instead of payload, insert data into query paramaters. It will be:

```
request_url = request_url + '?' + data
```

And remove `data` from the constructor `urllib2.Request(...)`